# Radeon 7850 graphics card driver on ubuntu 20.04: how do I change it to amdgpu? (it is currently radeon)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 and I want to change my graphics card driver to amdgpu. it is currently set at its default driver of "radeon". I tried to find AMD's driver files from their website but the most up-to-date driver for the Radeon 7850 is for ubuntu 18.04.2. Does this mean I cannot get the "amdgpu" driver without loading an earlier ubuntu version on my computer? I've tried lots of different code I've found around the internet but to no avail.